# Codeigniter and RewriteRule problem

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I've been puzzling over this none for a while. This is the rewrite rule that I've got at the moment:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^ext\/(.*)$ index.php/cproposal/key/$1 [NC]
```

Essentially I'm trying to get

```
http://localhost/cvc/ext/12445345346
```

to rewrite to

```
http://localhost/cvc/index.php/cproposal/key/12445345346
```

Codeigniter is producing a 404 however. If I change the `index.php/cproposal/key/$1` part of the rule to something inane like the Codeigniter license.txt thats found in the directory then it works but anything actually related to Codeigniter itself produces a 404.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Oh and I should mention that if I change the second part of the RewriteRule to the full url then it works.

Answer (score 2):

`mod_rewrite` is great, but Codeigniter already has a [built in solution](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html) for anything in your Codeigniter application.

Try adding this to your `config/routes.php`:

```
$route['ext/(:num)'] = 'cproposal/key/$1';
```

This would route requests for:

> `http://localhost/cvc/ext/{any_number}`

to

> `http://localhost/cvc/cproposal/key/{requested_number}`

The `index.php` will be optional, and dependent on your CI configuration. In other words, if you're using it already - it will be in the url. If not, it doesn't have to be.

All CI routes may use regular expressions in addition to the built in wildcards `(:num)` and `(:any)`, so feel free to get creative.

Comment: Thanks but it's acting strangely now, it's not loading sessions unless i use /cvc/ext/key/12423542 ?

Comment: What does "not loading sessions" mean exactly? And thanks for confirming this is within your CI app, my answer would be useless for anything outside of it, but it's the best (and most portable) solution if it is within CI. Also, what version of CI exactly?

Comment: By not loading sessions I mean that it's failing to load any data from sessions on that page. The version of CI I'm using is 2.0.2. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If the route itself is working, it's preferred that you opened a new question as this is a separate issue. If you do, please include your controller code.

Comment: By the way, sorry to not directly answer your question, but it seems that it should work. Did you try removing `index.php/` from the RewriteRule, or make sure to define it *before* the other rules? It'd be good to see the entire .htaccess